# Error happen when I send image from my app to a server

Tags: python, ios, swift, django, xcode

Error happen when I send image from my Swift app to my Django server.
I am making Swift app and I wanna make a system in my app which upload a image to my Django server.So in this time, when I run emulator(it is iPhone's emulator) of Xcode and I select image and I put "Send" button which send images to the server,I wanna send the image to my server.But the error happen.
Traceback(in Xcode) is

```
objc[31510]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices (0x11eab5998) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices (0x11d9a0880). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
2017-06-16 22:05:57.023485 Kenshin_Swift[31510:1318899] [Generic] Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error
2017-06-16 22:05:58.102220 Kenshin_Swift[31510:1319061] [] nw_endpoint_flow_prepare_output_frames [1 127.0.0.1:8000 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] Failed to use 1 frames, marking as failed
2017-06-16 22:05:58.104562 Kenshin_Swift[31510:1319027] [] nw_socket_write_close shutdown(13, SHUT_WR): [57] Socket is not connected
******* response = Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x60000023bc80> { URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/upload/post } { status code: 404, headers {
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Fri, 16 Jun 2017 13:05:58 GMT";
    Server = "WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.11";
    "X-Frame-Options" = SAMEORIGIN;
} })
****** response data = 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Page not found at /accounts/upload/post</title>
  <meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE">
  <style type="text/css">
    html * { padding:0; margin:0; }
    body * { padding:10px 20px; }
    body * * { padding:0; }
    body { font:small sans-serif; background:#eee; }
    body>div { border-bottom:1px solid #ddd; }
    h1 { font-weight:normal; margin-bottom:.4em; }
    h1 span { font-size:60%; color:#666; font-weight:normal; }
    table { border:none; border-collapse: collapse; width:100%; }
    td, th { vertical-align:top; padding:2px 3px; }
    th { width:12em; text-align:right; color:#666; padding-right:.5em; }
    #info { background:#f6f6f6; }
    #info ol { margin: 0.5em 4em; }
    #info ol li { font-family: monospace; }
    #summary { background: #ffc; }
    #explanation { background:#eee; border-bottom: 0px none; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="summary2017-06-16 22:05:58.104879 Kenshin_Swift[31510:1319027] [] nw_endpoint_flow_service_writes [1 127.0.0.1:8000 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] Write request has 0 frame count, 0 byte count
">
    <h1>Page not found <span>(404)</span></h1>
    <table class="meta">
      <tr>
        <th>Request Method:</th>
        <td>POST</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Request URL:</th>
        <td>http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/upload/post</td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="info">

      <p>
      Using the URLconf defined in <code>KenshinServer.urls</code>,
      Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
      </p>
      <ol>

          <li>

                ^admin/


          </li>

          <li>

                ^accounts/


                ^login/$
                [name='login']

          </li>

          <li>

                ^accounts/


                ^logout/$
                [name='logout']

          </li>

          <li>

                ^accounts/


                ^regist/$
                [name='regist']

          </li>

          <li>

                ^accounts/


                ^regist_save/$
                [name='regist_save']

          </li>

          <li>

                ^accounts/


                ^profile/$
                [name='profile']

          </li>

          <li>

                ^accounts/


                ^photo/$
                [name='photo']

          </li>

          <li>

                ^accounts/


                ^upload/(?P&lt;p_id&gt;\d+)/$
                [name='upload']

          </li>

          <li>

                ^accounts/


                ^upload_save/$
                [name='upload_save']

          </li>

          <li>

                ^accounts/


                ^kenshinresults$
                [name='kenshinresults']

          </li>

          <li>

                ^accounts/


                ^tcresults$
                [name='tcresults']

          </li>

          <li>

                ^api/


          </li>

          <li>

                ^accounts/


                ^login/$
                [name='login']

          </li>

          <li>

                ^accounts/


                ^logout/$
                [name='logout']

          </li>

          <li>

                ^accounts/


                ^regist/$
                [name='regist']
        2017-06-16 22:05:58.106707 Kenshin_Swift[31510:1319056] [] __tcp_connection_write_eof_block_invoke Write close callback received error: [89] Operation canceled

          </li>

          <li>

                ^accounts/


                ^regist_save/$
                [name='regist_save']

          </li>

          <li>

                ^accounts/


                ^profile/$
                [name='profile']

          </li>

          <li>

                ^accounts/


                ^photo/$
                [name='photo']

          </li>

          <li>

                ^accounts/


                ^upload/(?P&lt;p_id&gt;\d+)/$
                [name='upload']

          </li>

          <li>

                ^accounts/


                ^upload_save/$
                [name='upload_save']

          </li>

          <li>

                ^accounts/


                ^kenshinresults$
                [name='kenshinresults']

          </li>

          <li>

                ^accounts/


                ^tcresults$
                [name='tcresults']

          </li>

          <li>

                ^ResultJSON/


          </li>

          <li>

                ^api/1.0/


          </li>

          <li>

                ^api/1.0/login/


          </li>

          <li>

                ^image\/(?P&lt;path&gt;.*)$


          </li>

      </ol>
      <p>The current URL, <code>accounts/upload/post</code>, didn't match any of these.</p>

  </div>

  <div id="explanation">
    <p>
      You're seeing this error because you have <code>DEBUG = True</code> in
      your Django settings file. Change that to <code>False</code>, and Django
      will display a standard 404 page.
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>

Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
```

I read this error in web and I think the error is caused by wrong url.So I think the url `let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/upload/post");`
in Swift is wrong.
But I think it is right url.
I wrote codes of Server/accounts/views.py in Django server,

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST
from .forms import RegisterForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from .models import Post
from .forms import UserImageForm
from .models import ImageAndUser

def index(request):
    context = {
        'user': request.user,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/index.html', context)

@login_required
def profile(request):
    context = {
        'user': request.user,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/profile.html', context)

def regist(request):
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/regist.html', context)

def index(request):
    context = {
        'user': request.user,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/index.html', context)


@login_required
def profile(request):
    context = {
        'user': request.user,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/profile.html', context)

def regist(request):
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/regist.html', context)

@require_POST
def regist_save(request):
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()
        login(request, user)
        context = {
            'user': request.user,
        }
        return redirect('profile')


    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/regist.html', context)

@login_required
def photo(request):
    d = {
        'photos': Post.objects.all(),
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/profile.html', d)


def upload(request, p_id):
    form = UserImageForm(request.POST or None)
    d = {
        'p_id': p_id,
        'form':form,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/photo.html', d)


def upload_save(request):

    photo_id = request.POST.get("p_id", "")

    if (photo_id):
        photo_obj = Post.objects.get(id=photo_id)
    else:
        photo_obj = Post()

    files = request.FILES.getlist("files[]")
    photo_obj.image = files[0]
    # photo_obj.image2 = files[1]
    # photo_obj.image3 = files[2]

    photo_obj.save()
    # return render(request, "registration/accounts/photo.html")

    photos = Post.objects.all()
    context = {
        'photos': photos,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/photo.html', context)

def kenshinresults(request):
    d = {
        'results': results,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/kenshin_result.html', d)

def tc(request):
    tcresults = ImageAndUser.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('id').last()
    d = {
        'tcresults': tcresults,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/tc.html', d)
```

and I wrote codes in Server/accounts/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', login,
        {'template_name': 'registration/accounts/login.html'},
        name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^regist/$', views.regist,name='regist' ),
    url(r'^regist_save/$', views.regist_save, name='regist_save'),
    url(r'^profile/$', views.profile, name='profile'),
    url(r'^photo/$', views.photo, name='photo'),
    url(r'^upload/(?P<p_id>\d+)/$', views.upload, name='upload'),
    url(r'^upload_save/$', views.upload_save, name='upload_save'),
    url(r'^kenshinresults$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='registration/accounts/kenshin_result.html'),
        name='kenshinresults'),
    url(r'^tcresults$', views.tc,name='tcresults'),
]
```

Therefore,`let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/upload/post");`  is right url and I think this method is for posting images to my server.
Which part do i make a mistake?
How can I fix this error?

I changed url before one into `let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/upload_save/");`,but in this time I got an error,

```
objc[31747]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices (0x11aa7d998) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices (0x119968880). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
2017-06-16 23:11:52.837756 Kenshin_Swift[31747:1350088] [Generic] Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error
2017-06-16 23:11:54.274757 Kenshin_Swift[31747:1350153] [] nw_socket_get_input_frames recvmsg(fd 13, 1024 bytes): [54] Connection reset by peer
2017-06-16 23:11:54.276896 Kenshin_Swift[31747:1350153] [] nw_endpoint_flow_prepare_output_frames [1 127.0.0.1:8000 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] Failed to use 1 frames, marking as failed
2017-06-16 23:11:54.277301 Kenshin_Swift[31747:1350153] [] nw_socket_write_close shutdown(13, SHUT_WR): [57] Socket is not connected
2017-06-16 23:11:54.277684 Kenshin_Swift[31747:1350153] [] nw_endpoint_flow_service_writes [1 127.0.0.1:8000 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] Write request has 0 frame count, 0 byte count
2017-06-16 23:11:54.278467 Kenshin_Swift[31747:1350154] [] __tcp_connection_write_eof_block_invoke Write close callback received error: [89] Operation canceled
error=Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x60800025cda0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/upload_save/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/upload_save/, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.})
```

What is wrong?Is it not server's url wrong?

Comment: Can you update the code of image picking & uploading to server?

Answer (score 0):

You're sending the image to the path `/accounts/upload/post` but you don't have a URL defined which matches that path.

Did you perhaps mean `/accounts/upload_save/`?

Comment: Your saying is right, so I wrote url like let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/upload_save/"),but in this time,I got an error.I updated my question, so if u know something, please tell me.